# How to make a function to calculate the date and month of the year automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to ask how to make a function javascript reactjs calculate the date and month of the year automatically with a distance of 10 days from 17-10-2020, after calculating from 17-10-2020 it will be like this 27-10-2020

Comment: There are libraries for that such as: https://momentjs.com/. Do you have to implement it yourself?

Comment: You want a function that takes a date input and returns a date 10 days in the future?

Comment: Yes, it is true

Comment: if You decide to use Moment.js the following would work `date.add(10, "days")` where `date` is a Moment.js object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should work:

```js
const tenDaysInFuture = date => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);
    newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
    return newDate;
}

console.log(tenDaysInFuture(new Date('2020-09-29')));
console.log(tenDaysInFuture(new Date('2020-09-09')));
console.log(tenDaysInFuture(new Date('2020-10-17')));
```